# Ubuntu 19.04 + Postfix + Dovecot: Thunderbird не отправляет почту

Tags: smtp, thunderbird

Всем привет!
Такая проблема, при попытке отправить почту с Thunderbird, получаю следующее сообщение:

> Ошибка отправления сообщения.
>   Отправка сообщения с использованием Сервера исходящей почты (SMTP)  не удалась по неизвестной причине. Убедитесь, что указали корректные параметры Сервера исходящей почты (SMTP) и попробуйте снова.

Я уже пинал на то, что не правильно что-то настроил у себя на сервере, поэтому перерыл все параметры как в постфиксе так и в довкоте. Пересмотрев внимательно попытался с другого почтового клиента зайти на почту и отправить письмо(myMail на iOS) - все отработало замечательно, никаких ошибок, письма приходят и уходят, а проблема с тандербирдом как была так и осталась. Перерыл поиском и SO и всевозможные форумы, но подходящего решения не нашел. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Конечно с таким кто-то уже обязательно сталкивался. Что говорят логи постфикса в момент отправки сандербёрдом?

Comment: @de_frag ругается на SASL LOGIN authentication failed:
в тандерберде пробовал как через SSL/TLS так и STARTTLS - результат одинаковый в обеих случаях

Comment: Покажите настройки Thunderbird

Comment: @sanmai http://prntscr.com/odwufc

Comment: Зря вы имя сервера убрали. Порт открыт? SSL сертификат корректный?

Comment: @sanmai да, иначе не только Thunderbird не мог бы отправлять письма, а так, что myMail на iOS, что Mailbird на win(с теми же идентичными настройками) - спокойно их отправляют, и только Thunderbird все никак не может подружиться с smtp.
При этом, если с myMail все отправленные раннее письма видны нормально, то Thunderbird зачем-то попытался собственную директорию отправленных писем создать, и их видно в общем-то, но только если они  отправлены с Mailbird(так как с тандербирда они по прежнему не хотят отправляться)

Comment: Так, теперь я вообще ничего не понимаю
Создал дополнительную учетку(отличную от той, которую создавал при настройке postfix и dovecot), и у нее уже все нормально и с тандербирда спокойно отправляются письма

Comment: Технически, можно сказать вопрос решен, но вот что не так с самой первой учеткой и почему у нее проблемы с тандербирдом - я так и не понял